# How to type memory instructions/opcodes properly for writing/modifying memory address while debugging kernel in GDB

Tags: debugging, assembly, linux-kernel, gdb, embedded-linux

Assume I have disassembly of 4 instructions starting from address `0x809fff00`:

```
(gdb) disas /r 0x809fff00, +0x10
Dump of assembler code from 0x809fff00 to 0x809fff10:
   0x809fff00:  00 35 0c 00 sll a2,t4,0x14
   0x809fff04:  00 00 00 00 nop
   0x809fff08:  00 00 00 00 nop
   0x809fff0c:  00 00 00 00 nop
```

and I want to modify the address 0x809fff00 with the opcodes 01 02 03 04 with little endian. How should i do it?

For instance in C, i would do like:
address 0x809fff00 = "\x04\x03\x02\01"

How to do it with `set` command in GDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know the opcodes, it's pretty simple. You just use `set` to set whatever bytes you want at that address. The only trick is that you want to set 4 bytes at a time, so you'll need to instruct `set` to treat the address as a pointer to a DWORD. You can do this with a C-style cast:

```
set *(unsigned int*)0x809fff10 = 0x04030201
```

(This, obviously, assumes that an `unsigned int` is a 4-byte type on your platform. If it isn't, change it as appropriate.)

Comment: I actually tried exactly the same with the difference of not typing unsigned int.